# Entity inner join em LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Queria fazer um inner join de modo que eu obtenha uma lista com os nomes dos `Logins` a partir da Lista de inteiro de `UsuarioID` da classe `LoginsAtivos`.

```
public class Login
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Senha {get;set; }
}

 public class LoginAtivo {
    public virtual int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public DateTime inicio { get; set; }
}
```

estou travado na seguinte função

```
context.LoginsAtivos.ToList();
```

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Como esta a lista de inteiros ? E porque inner join?

Comment: @jbueno eu completei minha pergunta
@MarconcílioSouza a lista de inteiro vem do int UsuarioID. e eu queria fazer um inner join porque meu ponto de partida é o `LoginsAtivos` e quero ter a lista de nome do `Login`

Comment: Acho que não entendi sua dúvida. Você tem uma lista de `LoginAtivo` e quer saber qual o `Login` ele pertence?
Se você normalizar e adicionar os relacionamentos em `LoginAtivo` e `Login`, você consegue obter os valores que deseja apenas com `context.LoginsAtivos.ToList();`.

Comment: @Randrade isso msm. Queria saber como.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguir solucionar meu problema com o seguinte código utilizando a sintaxe lambda. Nele eu cito a tabela que eu quero agrupar `LoginDao.getListUsuario()`. Faço a junção da tabela e depois seleciono os nomes dos usuarios ativo `(ativo, login) => login.Nome`

```
public static List<string> getListUsuario() {
            return contexto.LoginAtivo
                .Join(LoginDao.getListUsuario(),
                    ativo => ativo.UsuarioID,
                    login => login.ID,
                    (ativo, login) => login.Nome)
                .ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

> Irei responder com a premissa que a relação seja de **1:N** entre `Login` e `LoginAtivo`.

Se você fizer uma modelagem correta, o **Entity Framework** faz esse trabalho todo para você. Para isso, vamos ajustar algumas coisas em sua estrutura.

```
public class Login
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Senha {get;set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LoginAtivo> LoginsAtivos{get;set;}
}

 public class LoginAtivo {

    [Key, ForeignKey("Login")]
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public DateTime inicio { get; set; }

   public virtual Login Login{get;set;}
}
```

Dessa forma, basta fazer a consulta normal que está fazendo `context.LoginsAtivos.ToList();` que cada `LoginAtivo` terá seu `Login`, e você poderá acessar pela propriedade de navegação, exemplo: `loginAtivo.Login.Nome`, onde `loginAtivo` é um item da lista (retorno da sua consulta no banco).

Comment: 1 para N ou 1 para 1?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez No contexto da minha resposta, um Login pode ter vários LoginsAtivos, então  1 para 1 não ficaria bem. Mas o AP não explicou direito, então...

Comment: Sua resposta está perfeita para 1:0-1. Até seria melhor colocar algumas considerações a respeito. A meu ver, seria a melhor abordagem.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez No caso, um login pode ter 0 ou N LoginsAtivos, então 1:1 não se encaixa nesta visão. Agora, um LoginAtivo pode ter 1 Login, dessa forma sim, 1:1. Mas irei editar a resposta e acrescentar mais alguns detalhes.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um método de extensão para fazer isso.

> Chame assim.

```
context.LoginsAtivos
.Vw_LoginAtivoLogin(context);
```

> Tipo uma View.

```
public class vw_LoginAtivoLogin {
    public LoginAtivo loginAtivo { get; set; }
    public Login login { get; set; }
}
```

> Método.

```
public static class LoginExt
{
    public static IQueryable<vw_LoginAtivoLogin> Vw_LoginAtivoLogin(
        this IQueryable<LoginAtivo> qrIn, WdbContext ctx)
    {
        return qrIn
            .Select(LA =>
                new vw_LoginAtivoLogin
                {
                    loginAtivo = LA,
                    login = ctx.Login.FirstOrDefault(L =>  L.ID == LA.UsuarioID),
                });
    }
}
```

Caso a relação seja 1:N, altere o `FirstOrDefault` por `Where` e a view para

```
public class vw_LoginAtivoLogin {
    public LoginAtivo loginAtivo { get; set; }
    public List<Login> login { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Login
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Senha {get;set; }
}

 public class LoginAtivo {
    public virtual int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public DateTime inicio { get; set; }
}


var nomes = from login in contexto.listloginativo()( contexto LoginAtivo)   join
            user in  contexto.listlogin() (contexto do login) on login.UsuarioId equals user.ID 
            select user.Nome;
```

Ou algo assim